# SpringBoot oAuth2 Location Header

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth

I have three micro-services

- gateway (Spring Cloud Gateway)
- security
- insurance

All the requests are made to the gateway service on port 8080 that redirect them to the specific service

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator myRoutes (
            RouteLocatorBuilder builder
    ) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p.path("/auth/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("^/auth", ""))
                        .uri(authServiceUri))
                .route(p -> p
                        .path("/payments/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("^/payments", ""))
                        .uri(paymentServiceUri)
                )
                .route(p -> p
                        .path("/insurance/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("^/insurance", ""))
                        .uri(insuranceServiceUri)
                )
                .build();
    }
```

If i navigate to /insurance oAuth redirects me to the login page (api.domain.com/auth/login), after that a POST request is made by the login form with user credentials (api.domain.com/auth/login), this request (if succesful) contains a Location Header that redirects the user to the /oauth/authorize endpoint.

The problem is that this header does not contain the gateway service URL (api.domain.com:8080/auth) but it contains the direct service url (http://localhost:9999) how can i fix this? How to tell to Spring oAuth to send back a redirect  to the gateway server instead of the service url?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to set `server.forward-headers-strategy=framework` on the auth server?

Comment: Please @Welsh add this as an answer so I can give you reputation... I lost literally 1 day on this issue and i was pretty sure it was related to X-Forward header but none of my researches led me to the server.forward-headers-strategy! If there is a way to buy you a beer i would.

Comment: Added and glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following property on the Auth Server:

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=framework
```

Some additional information on this can be found in the [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-behind-a-proxy-server).

Comment: I am using springboot 1.5.18.RELEASE version, but adding this property does not solve the problem. could you please more brief for how to use it and springboot version too?